# How do I install the VirtualBox guest tools on Xubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox, root, xubuntu

I am relatively new to Linux and have installed VirtualBox with Xubuntu on my computer; however the screen resolution is low and stays that way. I found that installing Guest Additions should solve it. But in order to do that, I have to run the installation as root.

How do I run the installation as root?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever you type 'sudo', without quotes, before a command, you run it as root.

e.g. sudo vi /var/www/html/index.php
this command will run the vi-editor as root and open the index.php file from your local web server.

When issuing the sudo command, you will be asked to enter your password, and you will be granted root access for the given command if you are allowed to run sudo!

If you don't belong to the sudoers or wheel group, you can still gain root access by changing your user account on the command line.
You use the command 'su'. You will be asked for the root password however, so you should know it.

Answer (score 0):

go to top left Player>manage> install vmaware tools
u will have a virtual dvd icon on your desktop in guest. if not, just mount it. browse into dvd, fild the tar file. untar it. u will find installable file with .pl format . run it in terminal command and say yes to all questions. incase u got error for kernel header, doe as follow:
sudo apt-get install "your linux header"

to find linux header, in terminal command type: uname -r

Answer (score -1):

Root is the master account in Ubuntu; the root account has no limitations. To get access as root. You can type:

sudo  and Ubuntu will ask you for your password and then execute that command as root.

Or

sudo -s where you'll input your password and then you will become the root user

Answer (score -2):

You can use the sudo command to run as the superuser (root).  Type sudo [command] in a terminal window to run it as root (it will prompt for a password, type your user's password. If you want to know about other features of sudo you simply type man sudo at a terminal window to get you variants syntax.